# what's the part of speech of "nothing but"?

Tags: prepositions, parts-of-speech

I am curious what the part of speech of "nothing but" is. I have some examples:

1. We could see nothing but fog.
2. nothing but the best will do.

In my opinion, there's no difference between "nothing but" and "only". So I think the part of speech of "nothing but" is adv.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Nothing but* is not a part of speech.

*Nothing* is a pronoun meaning "no thing". *But* is a preposition meaning "except", and taking *fog* as its object; the preposition phrase *but fog* modifies *nothing*.

Note that the PP can be separated from its host:

> There was nothing we could see but fog.
>   Nothing will do but the best.

Answer (score 1):

"but" also replaces "except" in grammar. A preposition.

e.g.,

*Visibility was down to zero, there was nothing but fog.*

Answer (score 0):

In your sentence, NOTHING BUT is an adverbial phrase.

Nothing (pronoun)  + but (except, preposition)

= Nothing but ( only) ----->> Adverbial Phrase.